# best way to write data to a sqlite from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

I am creating a monitoring application. I want to read queries from all the servers and store it in a sqlite file. Display it whenever it is required. I am using c++ to write this application - to fetch and store data from multiple servers to a single sqlite database. I am using separate threads to fetch data from multiple servers. If I fetch and write data to sqlite directly then it may lock sqlite file as 100s of threads will be writing at the same time. 
What is the best way to write data to a sqlite from multiple threads?

Comment: [The X-Y solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Consider reducing the thread count with `select`, `epoll`, Overlapped IO or whatever IO multiplexer is best supported by your operating system.

Comment: edited my question. I cannot reduce the thread count it depends on the numbers of servers connected.

Comment: Right, but with a multiplexer one thread can manage many servers.

Comment: To reinforce user4581301's comment, remember that all that network traffic from those multiple servers is all going through the single network interface on your computer. It may appear that you're accessing multiple servers simultaneously in multiple threads, but the access is serialised as a result of this all happening over your network. So a single thread can just as easily handle several server connections as multiple threads, probably.

Comment: I'd also like to strongly suggest you reconsider  user4581301's comment. Google "the c10k" problem. You're probably misusing threads.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a better way to do this with sqlite if you cannot control the number of simultaneous write actions.

SQLite is not designed for your use case. Consider switching to a Client/Server RDBMS. This is also what SQLite advises:

https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

> **Situations Where A Client/Server RDBMS May Work Better**
>
> **Client/Server Applications**
>
> If there are many client programs sending SQL to the same database over a network, then use a client/server database engine instead of
>   SQLite. SQLite will work over a network filesystem, but because of the
>   latency associated with most network filesystems, performance will not
>   be great. Also, file locking logic is buggy in many network filesystem
>   implementations (on both Unix and Windows). If file locking does not
>   work correctly, two or more clients might try to modify the same part
>   of the same database at the same time, resulting in corruption.
>   Because this problem results from bugs in the underlying filesystem
>   implementation, there is nothing SQLite can do to prevent it.
>
> A good rule of thumb is to avoid using SQLite in situations where the same database will be accessed directly (without an intervening
>   application server) and simultaneously from many computers over a
>   network.
>
> (...)
>
> **High Concurrency**
>
> SQLite supports an unlimited number of simultaneous readers, but it will only allow one writer at any instant in time. For many
>   situations, this is not a problem. Writer queue up. Each application
>   does its database work quickly and moves on, and no lock lasts for
>   more than a few dozen milliseconds. But there are some applications
>   that require more concurrency, and those applications may need to seek
>   a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use messages queue like RabbitMQ or Redis to solve that kind of problem

1. Send your data to the queue, which is good at async inserts
2. Create a worker-thread, that will take new messages from the queue
3. Use that worker to insert new messages to SQLite

With this architecture, only one worker-thread will write to a database, and there will be no locking problems, as it's ok for SQLite to work in "one writer multiple readers" mode

Answer (score -3):

Use only one sqlite database connection for all threads, opened with flag [SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) set.
Database will then serialize writes from all of the threads and there will be no locking.
But you need to tune your database and application design so write queries run fast enough, how much is required.

Comment: FULLMUTEX is _the most_ locking, not no locking. It also only affects the connection object, which you should never share among threads anyway for various reasons (each thread should have their own connection).

Comment: For database write operations in the end you always have locking of table rows and/or table pages, which could lead to deadlocks. It is always advisable to have only one database writer thread/process or to use FULLMUTEX.
Additional refinement can be that threads which write to same tables should have locking and threads which write to different tables not.
For read operations there's no need for serialization and they can run in parallel.

Comment: SQLite uses a single lock for the entire database. There's no possibility of a deadlock. And again, `FULLMUTEX` protects the _connection object_, which shouldn't be shared among threads anyway because it makes using transactions impossible.

Comment: You're in contradiction with yourself and the question asked. The question was:
"What is the best way to write data to a sqlite from multiple threads?"
So your comment "connection object, which shouldn't be shared among threads" contradicts to what is asked. Here access from multiple threads is reqired and only safe way to achieve this is with mutexes.

Comment: _"each thread should have their own connection"_ You can have multiple connections to the same database. The connections will handle locking around transactions.